# SharePoint 2013 OOTB Blog webpart zones

Tags: 2013

I've run into a problem after creating a OOTB blog in our environment where the web part zone "Blog navigator" and "Left" are floating into each other, giving the blog a strange look when trying to use the Inline template. The date CSS floats into the title. Trying to set the web part to a specific size does not help.

[image]

And when clicking on one of the archive categories, The message floats into the "Blog tools".

[image]

Is this a standard behavior? We have no custom master page nor custom CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the same on a SharePoint 2013 installation with SP1 without customization.

Tested with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, all showing the same results. So I assume this is indeed standard behavior.

At least to change the position of the "Blog tools" I've successfully used some CSS tweaks, but never had the time to check if some CSS tricks could be used to fix the page in edit mode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess i just have to live with that for now, hopefully the blog owner wont care to much about it.